# Is it possible to give a classname to specific comments in the Wordpress admin?

Tags: wp-query, wp-admin, comments, seo, comments-template

Is this possible? I'd like to go into wp-admin, click on a comment and give a class for a specific comment. Would it be possible to do so? If so, could you please help?

Comment: I've removed the SEO part of the question as that isn't in this stacks scope. What are you trying to do that needs this?

Comment: I am trying to add a classname to a specific comment (manually) because I need to classify it and style it specifically based on some outcomes. I don't want to use if statements with comment IDs...

Comment: Or let me put it like this: I need to add an image in a comment depending on if that classname is there or not.

Comment: Which outcomes? Comments already have a selection of class names that get applied based on existing rules, there's a very high chance that what you want has already been done, or can be done using CSS rules. What is the condition for a comment having the class name added? A specific use case will help people understand as well as get you better answers

Comment: Well, yes, but comments have all the same classnames. I want to mark a comment manually (to get a specific class) depending on some manual outcomes (it's really picking out a comment because I need to do something with it) via wp-admin so that I know that specific comment gets that classname so that I can add the image and style it.

Comment: Can you provide the reasoning behind that though? What you've described is very generic and ambiguous, as if you're trying to hide what you need to do. HTML classes are not the only way to attach an image to a comment, and comments do have different classes names if they're implemented correctly. E.g. are you trying to mark a single comment as the correct answer and put a solution badge image on it? Or mark comments from particular users with a label? Please be specific

Comment: It's actually more like an "editor pick" thing. Nothing to hide there. I just want to mark a comment we like via the wp-admin manually to style this properly. That's it really. And I was wondering if it's possible to do so.

Comment: ok that's helpful to know and eliminates a number of solutions and approaches

Comment: Thanks Tom! May I know what my options are?

Comment: Nobody who can help here?